# gcc 4.7.3 internal compiler error when using make_shared with a constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr

I understand where the problem is, I'm just not sure why am I not getting any error output from gcc.

The lines in question which generate the issue are:

```
std::string type,rel,pred;
std::tie( type, rel, pred ) = tuple;
auto supertype = std::make_shared<Node>( Token( type ) ); // This
auto predicate = std::make_shared<Node>( Token( pred ) ); // and this
```

FYI, Node Ctor is:

```
Node ( Token & token )
```

If I do this, I get no error:

```
auto type_token = Token( type );
auto pred_token = Token( pred );
auto supertype = std::make_shared<Node>( type_token );
auto predicate = std::make_shared<Node>( pred_token );
```

My GCC is:

> posix gcc version 4.7.3 (Debian 4.7.3-8)

The actual error is:

```
> Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered. Please
> submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See
> <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Funnily enough, this directory above doesn't even exist.

What's wrong with constructing an object within the make_shared constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary object cannot bind to a non-`const` lvalue reference. You therefore cannot pass one to the specified `Node` constructor. The compiler should reject:

```
Node node1(Token(type));
Node node2(Token(pred));
```

The same is true for trying to get `std::make_shared` to perform the same initialization internally with your code:

```
auto supertype = std::make_shared<Node>( Token( type ) );
auto predicate = std::make_shared<Node>( Token( pred ) );
```

You are trying to get `make_shared` to pass that temporary object to the non-`const` lvalue constructor. The compiler should diagnose the program as ill-formed and fail to compile it. That is notably NOT the same thing as crashing with an ICE, which always indicates a compiler bug.

Workaround is to either do as you suggest in your "but this does work" code - pass an lvalue reference to `make_shared` - or to write an rvalue reference constructor for `Node`:

```
Node(Token&&);
```

EDIT: I think this is [GCC bug# 56869](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56869) which appears to have been fixed in 4.6.4 and 4.7.4 and was closed on 2013-11-18. If anyone reading this can easily run this testcase in 4.7.4:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Token {
  Token(std::string lex);
};

struct Node {
  Node(Token& token);
};

int main() {
    auto supertype = std::make_shared<Node>(Token{"foo"});
    auto predicate = std::make_shared<Node>(Token{"bar"});
}
```

please post the results in a comment.

Comment: Ty for the answer. Out of curiosity, this^^ is true for temporary objects, but **not** heap allocated objects, e.g. std::make_shared<Node>( new Token( foo ) ), assuming the constructor would accept a pointer. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f94c856dd5f3800b

Comment: GCC 4.8 compiles this program correctly, [spewing a ton of error messages.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/777204dbaf03dc45)

Comment: @Alex It's true for rvalues, which would be temporaries, function return values, and the result of `std::move(...)` on an lvalue. A pointer would be fine.